# IE7 & IE8 Padding/margin problems

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, padding, margin

I've already posted this problem but i didn't manage to resolve the issue from the answers i received... Hopefully i will get lucky this time.

I've also include all the code etc... so this should make it easy to pin point the issue.

**IE7 Screen shot** 
[image: IE7 Screen shot]

**IE8 Screen shot** 
[image: IE8 Screen shot]

[please see the HTML & CSS for the entire website](http://freetexthost.com/5aujac0hob)

Any help would be much appreciated, I can't load the new homepage until this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using a global reset css file? Apologies if you are using this already but i couldnt locate reference to it. YUI one is good - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/. They are good for getting all styles back to a consistent base removing any defaults that a browser may introduce.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by simplifying everything.  In other words, start a new html file, then start putting in the framework.  Make sure it looks right, then add more.  Go slow, at some point you'll find the problem.

Comment: When i insert the interconnect logo it pushes up the globe image... it seems to be an hidden div?

Comment: What happens when you take that search <form> tag out?

Comment: Also, it would be much easier to help if you had this on a live site somewhere.  There seems to be a lot of .css file references in the source, which aren't really represented in the css blob at the bottom.  Sometimes they step on each other...